# Android VideoView streaming

Tags: android, encoding, streaming, mp4, android-videoview

I have a project with a VideoView in it I am streaming a video from online using this method:

```
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://db.tt/ij7w1Nw"));
```

My videos are mp4 files downloaded from Youtube. I then upload them to my dropbox, that is where the url comes from. This works fine if I download the video and do not make any changes to it, and upload it straight to dropbox. However if I try to make any changes to it for instance convert from .flv to .mp4, or change the size, then I upload it to dropbox it no longer plays in the VideoView. I get a dialog that says 'Unable to play video. Invalid streaming data'. If I take this same exact video and put it on the SD card either manually or even by having my app download it from the url then play it off of the SD card using

```
mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
```

it works fine. I am using Wondershare Video Converter Platinum to do the conversions and size changes.

Is there some sort of specific encoding that is required to stream an mp4 file rather than play it from a local copy? Am I getting this because of some sort of bug/error with wondershare? Has anyone else experienced this type of problem, if so how did you end up fixing it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The [media format guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) may help you see what's available. In my experience wrapping a H.264 AVC or MPEG 4-encoded video in a 3GPP container provides the easiest integration. Android is very fickle with both audio and video streaming.